# How to conditionally apply state provider in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            access: 0
        })
```

here i want to write

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            if(isAvailable){
              templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
            }
         else{
          //other url              
           }

        })
```

conditionally i have to show either of the view .Is this achievable in config file itself . Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `templateProvider` config with [`$templateFactory`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$templateFactory). For example

```
url: '/login',
controller: 'LoginController',
templateProvider: function($templateFactory, availabilityService) {
    var url = availabilityService.isAvailable() ?
        'login/login.html' : 'other/url.html';
    return $templateFactory.fromUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: thanks . function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $sceProvider, $httpProvider,$templateFactory)
{ // }   Do i need to inject any depandancies

Comment: @prash the `templateProvider` function is injectable so just inject what you need there (as I've shown with `$templateFactory` and the made up `availabilityService`)